# Incorrect date at print

Tags: mysql, date, symfony, doctrine, twig

im try to print the users birthday of my app, the dates are allowed in a database.
In the DB have the user #37 with birthday at '1900-01-01'.

The User model defines, birthday, accessors and property as follow:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date")
 */
 protected $fechaDeNacimiento;

/**
 * @param \DateTime $fechaDeNacimiento
 * @return User
 */
 public function setFechaDeNacimiento($fechaDeNacimiento)
 {
   $this->fechaDeNacimiento = $fechaDeNacimiento;

   return $this;
 }

 /**
  * @return \DateTime 
  */
  public function getFechaDeNacimiento()
  {
    return $this->fechaDeNacimiento;
  }
```

With Twig i write:

```
{{ user.fechaDeNacimiento | date("m-d-Y")}}
```

But the result is not '01-01-1900', is '12-31-1899'. The format is correct, but the date not.

Any ideas ?.

Comment: What's your php timezone and mysql timezone?

Answer (score 1):

### Leap Second

This is due to [leap second](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second).

> A leap second is a one-second adjustment that is occasionally applied
>   to Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) in order to keep its time of day
>   close to the mean solar time.
>
> Specifically, a positive leap second is inserted between second
>   23:59:59 of a chosen UTC calendar date (the last day of a month,
>   usually June 30 or December 31) and second 00:00:00 of the following
>   date.

And indeed, a leap second has occurred in `12-31-1899` as referenced [here](http://www.quadibloc.com/science/cal06.htm).

---

### Edit

Most databases support **Time Zone Leap Second**, for example [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time-zone-leap-seconds.html)

To give you an idea, here is what happens for the leap second defined in `2008-12-31`

[That's a perfect example in 2008](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time-zone-leap-seconds.html):

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE t1 (
    ->   a INT,
    ->   ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW(),
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (ts)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> -- change to UTC
mysql> SET time_zone = '+00:00';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> -- Simulate NOW() = '2008-12-31 23:59:59'
mysql> SET timestamp = 1230767999;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO t1 (a) VALUES (1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> -- Simulate NOW() = '2008-12-31 23:59:60'
mysql> SET timestamp = 1230768000;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO t1 (a) VALUES (2);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> -- values differ internally but display the same
mysql> SELECT a, ts, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts) FROM t1;
+------+---------------------+--------------------+
| a    | ts                  | UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts) |
+------+---------------------+--------------------+
|    1 | 2008-12-31 23:59:59 |         1230767999 |
|    2 | 2008-12-31 23:59:59 |         1230768000 |
+------+---------------------+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> -- only the non-leap value matches
mysql> SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE ts = '2008-12-31 23:59:59';
+------+---------------------+
| a    | ts                  |
+------+---------------------+
|    1 | 2008-12-31 23:59:59 |
+------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```